# Why are my PHP errors not displaying?

Tags: php, error-handling

Here is my php.ini and I have restarted the httpd process several times while messing around with this, however no errors are being displayed, only a blank page.

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL & E_STRICT
display_errors = On
```

Comment: did you edit the correct php.ini? There is one for CLI and one for regular use, do a phpinfo() to make sure the settings are being set. Also try clearing the cache the blank page maybe cached and what you are getting on refresh are just the cached version.

Comment: Hi Patrick thanks for your answer actually Toto answered below properly it was an error in my syntax.  I actually did try the phpinfo() sorry for not specifying.

Answer (score 1):

In dev, we use this:

`error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT`

Comment: Wow, I did not think it was that simple, can you elaborate why PHP would look for Or rather than And?

Comment: `&` is used to remove `~` certain types of error like `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` (Show all errors, except for notices and coding standards warnings.)

Comment: BTW, in dev, you can also use `display_startup_errors = On` to spot some config issues.